# ANTRL 3 grammar omitted part of input source code

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I am using [this ANTLR 3 grammar](http://research.xebic.com/es3/) and ANTLRWorks for testing that grammar.

But I can't figure out why some parts of my input text are omitted.

I would like to rewrite this grammar and display every element (lparen, keywords, semicolon,..) of the source file (input) in AST / CST.

I've tried everything, but without success. Can someone who is experienced with ANTLR help me?

[image]

Parse tree:

[image: parse tree]

Comment: First off, if you want to display every token you will have to display the parse tree, not the AST, which by definition will lack this information. Then, why don't you try the ANTLR v4 [ECMAScript grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/ecmascript)?

Comment: Thank you for reply, but the problem is because I must use ANTLR v3 for this project and I need to create Concrete Syntax Trees (CST), so Parse Tree doesn't help me a lot. I need to have all source elements (lparen, keywords, dots, etc..) in AST.

Comment: In my understanding, *CST* is just a synonym of *parse tree*. I don't know what you're trying to do, but it seems to me you'll need to work at this level of abstraction, not at the *AST* level.

Comment: No, in my case CST is tree like this http://screencast.com/t/boejNTHqO4w, CST is look like AST (http://screencast.com/t/8mM3C2Jondu0), but it contains all source elements, without omitting anything (lparen, rparen, semicolons...)

Comment: I know how to translate from AST to CST, and that is not a question. Question is why and how this ANTRL 3 grammar (http://research.xebic.com/es3/) omitte and change input source code http://screencast.com/t/udoDpQXUmu, and because of that I can't display every element.

Comment: I have the same problem when I'm using Parse Tree: http://screencast.com/t/CfalAjYo3

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the complete parse tree you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60476/discussion-between-zoran-dukic-and-lucas-trzesniewski).

Comment: Don't mind that left pane in ANTLRWorks: look/inspect the actual parse tree by custom Java code (it will be the same as the big image on the right of the screen with the nodes and arrows). You will see that the parse tree has all tokens.

Comment: But I can't see WHILE keyword on the right side in the Parse tree...

Comment: @Zoran Sorry, but I was disconnected and didn't see your chat invitation. I took the liberty to include the parse tree you posted on the chat directly into your post. Indeed, the parse tree lacks some tokens. I'll take a look at the grammar later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to narrow it down to the `semic` rule:

```
/*
This rule handles semicolons reported by the lexer and situations where the ECMA 3 specification states there should be semicolons automaticly inserted.
The auto semicolons are not actually inserted but this rule behaves as if they were.

In the following situations an ECMA 3 parser should auto insert absent but grammaticly required semicolons:
- the current token is a right brace
- the current token is the end of file (EOF) token
- there is at least one end of line (EOL) token between the current token and the previous token.

The RBRACE is handled by matching it but not consuming it.
The EOF needs no further handling because it is not consumed by default.
The EOL situation is handled by promoting the EOL or MultiLineComment with an EOL present from off channel to on channel
and thus making it parseable instead of handling it as white space. This promoting is done in the action promoteEOL.
*/
semic
@init
{
    // Mark current position so we can unconsume a RBRACE.
    int marker = input.mark();
    // Promote EOL if appropriate   
    promoteEOL(retval);
}
    : SEMIC
    | EOF
    | RBRACE { input.rewind(marker); }
    | EOL | MultiLineComment // (with EOL in it)
    ;
```

So, the **EVIL** semicolon insertion strikes again!

I'm not really sure, but I think these `mark`/`rewind` calls are getting out of sync. The `@init` block is executed when the rule is entered for branch selection **and** for actual matching. It's actually creating a lot of marks but not cleaning them up. But I don't know why it messes up the parse tree like that.

Anyway, here's a working version of the same rule:

```
semic
@init
{
    // Promote EOL if appropriate   
    promoteEOL(retval);
}
    : SEMIC
    | EOF
    | { int pos = input.index(); } RBRACE { input.seek(pos); }
    | EOL | MultiLineComment // (with EOL in it)
    ;
```

It's much simpler and doesn't use the `mark/rewind` mechanism.

But there's a catch: the `semic` rule in the parse tree will have a child node `}` in the case of a semicolon insertion before a closing brace. Try to remove the semicolon after `i--` and see the result. You'll have to detect this and handle it in your code. `semic` should either contain a `;` token, or contain `EOL` (which means a semicolon got silently inserted at this point).

Comment: I'm so glad we got rid of `rewind` in ANTLR 4.